# Bottom overflowed by.. in the following code... I dont know where to put the scroll condition

Tags: flutter, listview, flexbox, singlechildscrollview

---

I am building an E Commerce app.. i have difficulty in this part of code.This code UI is not scrollable.. i need it scrollable.. I don't know where to add singleChildScrollView..The UI implementation of listview results in bottom overflowed.

code is given below:

```
Widget _cartItemsList() {
return new Consumer<CartProvider>(builder: (context, cartModel, child) {
  if (cartModel.cartItems != null && cartModel.cartItems.length > 0) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: cartModel.cartItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CartProduct(data: cartModel.cartItems[index]);
              },
            ),
            
        ),
        
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Loading....,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
});
```

}

Comment: wrap the `List View` with `Expanded` to get rid of `overflow`